# Wildcard search for file ending with not working on windows 11

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface, wildcard, git-bash

[![Here i'm trying to list all the files ending with by using *][1]][1]

> i'm trying to list all the files ending with s1.txt or .txt but wildcard file ending with not working ls -R *.txt

Comment: A suggestion.  Please remove the image and copy and paste the text in.  If you want other people to put some effort to help you, then it's only fair that you put in some effort to make it easy for the,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the "-R": `ls *.txt`

It should work like this.

Hope it helps! :)